# keras & tensorflow : using tfdbg with tensorboard

Tags: debugging, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I was trying to set up tfdbg in my training program with tensorboard.
I am using this command to start a debug session:

```
keras.backend.set_session(tf_debug.LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession(tf.Session(), "127.0.0.1:6064"))
```

but a `segmentation fault` error occurs when entering `run` on the console.

If I don't try to use tensorboard and omit the listener of the debug session. I don't get an error.

```
keras.backend.set_session(tf_debug.LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession(tf.Session()))
```

With this I can enter `run` command in the console without an error.

I have tried many running config including GPU and CPU run.

Do you have a solution for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong wrapper that's why I got this error:

for anyone who gets this error you should use this

```
`tf_debug.TensorBoardDebugWrapperSession(tf.Session(), "127.0.0.1:6064")`
```

instead of this

```
`tf_debug.LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession(tf.Session(), "127.0.0.1:6064")`
```